# Unable to delete "Wired connection 1" using nmcli

Tags: centos, networking, nmcli

Log:

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE
Wired connection 1  d1b2ff35-4d72-3bd5-a8e2-d3d9fefce205  802-3-ethernet  eth2
admin               6186afb2-7253-4805-9a10-5d13c6baca0f  802-3-ethernet  eth0
[root@oa1 ~]# nmcli c d "Wired connection 1"
Error: 'Wired connection 1' is not an active connection.
Error: no active connection provided.
```

When I tried to delete Wired connection 1 it says no active connection . How can I reset the network connection to initial OS configuration ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command:

```
nmcli connection delete connection_name
```

To  remove the `Wired connection 1`:

```
nmcli connection delete  "Wired connection 1"
```

or by its UUID:

```
nmcli connection delete d1b2ff35-4d72-3bd5-a8e2-d3d9fefce205
```

The [`man nmcli`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/nmcli.1.en.html):

> **CONNECTION MANAGEMENT COMMANDS**

```
nmcli connection {show | up | down | modify | add | edit | clone |
                    delete | monitor | reload | load | import | export}
                    [ARGUMENTS...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in shortening `delete` to just `d`, since there's more than one thing you can do with connections that starts with a D.

When you type `nmcli c d "Wired connection q"` , it assumes you meant `nmcli connection down...`, not `nmcli connection delete...`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes, use `\`:

```
nmcli connection delete Wired\ connection\ 1
```

If you try to ls into (with the tab) you will see exact spelling. For example,
/etc/SystemManager/Systemconnecitons

My system is down so sorry for exact spelling.